# issue with mongodb install on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am unable to install mongodb on ubuntu 20.02. Several suggestions endup in response to run

**sudo apt --fix-broken install**

however, when I run this, I get another set of errors

```
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      mongodb-org-database-tools-extra
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 256 not upgraded.
    3 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/7,744 B of archives.
    After this operation, 27.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
    (Reading database ... 371357 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-database-tools-extra_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking mongodb-org-database-tools-extra (6.0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-database-tools-extra_6.0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/install_compass', which is also in package mongodb-org-tools 4.2.14
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-database-tools-extra_6.0.1_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

did a

*sudo apt purge mongodb-org**

that cleared up the issues related to the package manager